# How to read text from 'simple' screenshot fast and effectively?

Tags: c#, ocr, screenshot

I'm working on a small personal application that should read some text (2 sentences at most) from a really simple Android screenshot. The text is always the same size, same font, and in approx. the same location. The background is very plain, usually a few shades of 1 color (think like bright orange fading into a little darker orange). I'm trying to figure out what would be the best way (and most importantly, the fastest way) to do this.

My first attempt involved the IronOcr C# library, and to be fair, it worked quite well! But I've noticed a few issues with it:

- It's not 100% accurate
- Despite having a community/trial version, it sometimes throws exceptions telling you to get a license
- It takes ~400ms to read a ~600x300 pixel image, which in the case of my simple image, I consider to be rather long

As strange as it sounds, I have a feeling that libraries like IronOcr and Tesseract may just be too advanced for my needs. To improve speeds I have even written a piece of code to "treshold" my image first, making it completely black and white.

My current IronOcr settings look like this:

```
            ImageReader = new AdvancedOcr()
            {
                CleanBackgroundNoise = false,
                EnhanceContrast = false,
                EnhanceResolution = false,
                Strategy = AdvancedOcr.OcrStrategy.Fast,
                ColorSpace = AdvancedOcr.OcrColorSpace.GrayScale,
                DetectWhiteTextOnDarkBackgrounds = true,
                InputImageType = AdvancedOcr.InputTypes.Snippet,
                RotateAndStraighten = false,
                ReadBarCodes = false,
                ColorDepth = 1
            };
```

And I could totally live with the results I've been getting using IronOcr, but the licensing exceptions ruin it. I also don't have $399 USD to spend on a private hobby project that won't even leave my own PC :(

But my main goal with this question is to find a better, faster or more efficient way to do this. It doesn't necessarily have to be an existing library, I'd be more than willing to make my own kind of letter-detection code that would work (only?) for screenshots like mine if someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: If the exceptions are truly random upon object creation...create a loop with a try catch trying to create the object instance multiple times if necessary...u r not going to be able to improve upon the performance of ocr software that cost millions to build as a single individual

Comment: @Ctznkane525 The exceptions aren't 'truly random', they're more than likely just being thrown because I'm trying to read images 'too frequently', although I haven't made sure of that yet. 

As for improving upon performance of OCR software: My intention is not to write my own full-fledged OCR software. It would be limited to the type of screenshots I need to read, which undoubtedly makes things a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I have researched about this topic and the best solution which I could find is Azure cognitive services. You can use Computer vision API to read text from an image. [Here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/computer-vision/) is the complete document.

Comment: I've seen that one indeed, but I always kind of assumed it wouldn't get the same speed as IronOcr because it requires you to upload your images too etc. Maybe I should give it a shot though! I'll update once I have.

Answer (score 0):

How fast does it have to be?
If you are using C# I recommend the Google [Cloud Vision API](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/libraries). You pay per request but the first 1000 per month are free (check pricing [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/)). **However**, it does require a web request but I find it to be very quick

```cs
using Google.Cloud.Vision.V1;
using System;

namespace GoogleCloudSamples
{
    public class QuickStart
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Instantiates a client
            var client = ImageAnnotatorClient.Create();
            // Load the image file into memory
            var image = Image.FromFile("wakeupcat.jpg");
            // Performs label detection on the image file
            var response = client.DetectText(image);
            foreach (var annotation in response)
            {
                if (annotation.Description != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(annotation.Description);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I find it works well for pictures and scanned documents so it should work perfectly for your situation. The SDK is also available in other languages too like Java, Python, and Node